# Как просмотреть данные, которые человек вводил на моем сайте?

Tags: email

Возникла проблема: в течение недели не приходили письма в следствие ошибки. При просмотре через веб-визор было видно, что масса клиентов оставляли заявки на обратный звонок, но при просмотре через веб-визор данные зашифрованы. Можно ли как-либо их открыть, либо просмотреть отправляемые данные через логи?

Comment: Скорее всего [не посмотреть](https://www.searchengines.ru/vebvizor-informatsia.html)